# Why I am to put images an Integer Array in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I am making the transition between iOS and Android, so this might be a very amateur question. But following an example online, I see that an array of images is actually an array of Integers:

```
// references to our images  
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_7, R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6
    };
```

Could somebody explain why I put them in `Integer Array`?

Comment: Those are resource identifiers I guess

Comment: You should use a primitive `int` array, unless you have some reason to use the `Integer` class.

Comment: Thanks.. in any case, I don't understand why this is an array of int/Integer instead of Image[] or similar.. Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @Chisko It matters because he wants to understand how his code works.  If you  want to write efficient code or debug problems, that's important.  Or if you want to design anything more complex than copy pasting examples.  It doesn't say good things about your professionalism that you don't want to know.

Comment: Hint: look at the variable name.

Comment: @GabeSechan then StackOverflow is not the place he's looking for. Perhaps he should start by going here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html or here https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837 because this question lacks the characteristics of a question as described here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

That is resource id of drawables (images).

Use like this:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.test_image);
image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[0]);
```

Here is good tutorial and document.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Working-with-the-ImageView

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

Android has a system called Resources.  These are pieces of data (usually integers, strings, color values, or drawables (images), but sometimes things like arrays or even files) that are built into the apk.  They are actually built into the app for speed.  These pieces of data are given integer id values, and basically looked up in a giant hashmap by id.  For drawables, anything in the res/drawable directory is treated this way, and given the id R.drawable.filename.

So images are using an array of int because its an array of those id values.  Basically an array of hash keys to look them up at runtime.  (The actual implementation isn't quite a hashmap, but its close enough you can think of it that way).

Answer (score 0):

As stated by this section:

```
// references to our images  
private Integer[] mThumbIds
```

It's literally just an array of reference Ids. The references are later used to tell the API what to load.

Comment: So why Integer? Wouldn't they be at the very least a string with the path?

Comment: Why waste 15-20 bytes when four bytes (int) can uniquely distinguish between more resources than you can physically hold on the device?

Answer (score 0):

If we keep any resource in `drawable` folder android `sdk` automatically generate unique integer value for that resource(image, xml file etc).

When we call  `R.drawable.resource_name` such as `R.drawable.sample_7` it return an `Integer` id.

That's why here in you code you need to put in a `Integer Array`.

### Note:

Not only for resource(image, xml etc) files but also for all UI component (Layout, Button, TextView, EditText etc ) unique id generated in `R.java` class under `gen` folder.

### We use

`R.id.ui_component_name` for (`Button, EditText, TextView, Spinner` etc),
`R.layout_layout_name` for (`Relative Layout`, Linear Layout etc)
`R.drawable.resource_name` for (`Image`, custom_views xml etc)

etc

Answer (score 0):

All the images put on the Drawable will be referenced by and integer id.
You can see at R.java file, all the strings, colors,layouts and images will be there.

So when you want to use, you just need to use the id in the R file  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html